# tracking when a certain field is created on a document

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I am trying to use change feed to track whenever a certain field is created on a document for a certain table, and receive the full doc when 
 that happens.

I have tried the following:

1.

```
const cursor = await r.table('tabley').hasFields('fieldy').changes().filter(
    r.row('old_val')('fieldy').eq(undefined)
).run(connection)
cursor.each(onFieldCreated)
```

2.

```
const cursor = await r.table('tabley').changes().filter(
    r.row('new_val')('fieldy').ne(r.row('old_val')('fieldy'))
).run(connection)
cursor.each(onFieldCreated)
```

These two examples and some more variants were agnostic to inserted `fieldy` values, doing nothing and giving no errors.

The best I got was to get changes on the given field, but then `new_val` and `old_val` only give the field value instead of the full document (id, etc), using this:

```
const cursor = await r.table('tabely')('fieldy').changes().run(connection)
cursor.each(onFieldCreated)
```